# How do I dependency inject a common interface into a low-level WPF style setter?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, wpf-style

I need to dependency inject an interface into my low level style setters for fundamental WPF elements like Label, TextBlock, etc.  I can't figure out how.

The settings are for things like FontSize, Button Size, colors, etc.  I used to store these in a common WPF Settings file (a .RESX file) in a shared assembly.   I could refer to it in any XAML file in any other assembly using `{x:Static}`:  For example:

```
<Style x:Key="TitleTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" 
            Value={Binding Source={x:Static coreModule:Properties.Settings.Default}, 
                           Path=FontSizeTitle}"/>

</Style>
```

But this ignored the DI approach I was already using, so I tried moving all settings to a dependency-injected interface.   Like this (but imagine many more properties):

```
public interface ISettings
{
    int FontSizeTitle { get; set; }
}
```

This is fine at a higher level, when I have one of my own view-models handy.  But my TextBlockStyle is at the very lowest level of my ResourceDictionary includes.  It cannot rely on a common datacontext type like that.  So what do I bind to in my style?

My workaround is a XAML MarkupExtension that does an end-run around everything and gets my ISettings interface anywhere in XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="TitleTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" 
            Value="{Binding Source={coreModule:Settings}, 
                            Path=FontSizeTitle}"/>
</Style>
```

It gets the Application object, assumes it implements ISettings and returns that.  A total hack that seems to defeats the purpose of dependency-injecting this interface.

```
namespace CoreModule.Extensions
{
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(ISettings))]
public class SettingsExtension : MarkupExtension
{   
    public SettingsExtension() { }

    // HACK: Just assume that the one and only app implements
    // the ISettings interface we need:

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) =>
        Application.Current as ISettings;

}}
```

I experimented with the `IServiceProvider` that WPF gives me in the markup extension but there seems to be no way to get at my own DI interfaces through that.

So how do I do this "right"?  Is there some better approach that actually works with the DI container to let me write low level styles with an injected interface?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using a `ResourceDictionary` to define your styles, instead?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.resourcedictionary

Comment: I am using a ResourceDictionary to define my styles.  I use several shared ResourceDictionaries in fact.  They are included in all my views.  The problem is that the Resource Dictionaries are stored down in the shared assemblies (so that all other assemblies can refer to them) not up at the top level where interfaces are injected